# Add multiple users to SharePoint Online document library item "Person or Group" column using Client Side Object Model (CSOM)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-api

I am attempting to add multiple users to a field using CSOM. However, only one person is being added even though both have been validated.

```
var newUserField = new List<SP.FieldUserValue>();
newUserField.Add(new FieldUserValue { LookupId = 14 });
newUserField.Add(new FieldUserValue { LookupId = 11 });
newListItem["MultiUserField"] = newUserField;
newListItem.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

That code always only adds user 14. I have also tried:

```
newListItem["MultiUserField"] = newUserField.ToArray();
```

Every reference I have seen says this should work, and it's not throwing any errors.

I have also verified the column allows multiple entries, and have added both users manually as a test. Could this be a document library CSOM limitation? Most references I have seen are using a list.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, during validating my users, I was calling a

```
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

that was wiping out what I had saved for the user. Validating the users first and storing their IDs in a list and then updating the item worked.

Comment: It seems that I have a similar issue in PowerShell CSOM context. Can you please share some more details / your new code, that I can better adapt? Here is my question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272870/write-multiple-people-in-multi-value-person-field-using-powershell-csom